# "She gave him the thumbs-up sign." and "She gave him a thumbs-up sign." What is the difference?

Tags: grammar

Could someone give me some situation examples that I can make sense out of the difference between them.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a case of different usages being appropriate to different situations, it's just different ways of thinking about the thumbs-up.

Using *a* treats the sign as an ordinary gesture, in the same way that we say *She gave him a wave/a smile*.

Using *the* treats it as a gesture with specific meaning ('all is well' or 'I'm OK with that'), as in *the Masonic handshake, the Nazi salute*.

Comment: Thanks Kate. With this in mind, it makes much more sense to say "She gave me the thumbs-up sign I could never forget."

Comment: Well, what if I got three thumbs-up signs from the same person in one day, should I use "a" to describe the first thumbs-up sign?

Comment: As I said, the _situation_ doesn't matter. _She gave me the thumbs-up sign_  = she made the conventional sign for indicating that all was well. _She gave me a thumbs-up sign_ = she gestured towards me with her thumb in the air. The difference is in how _you_ think of the sign.